# Stop Popover firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How do I stop a popover in a parent div from triggering when I click a child element?

```
<div data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-content="whatever">
  <a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Read more" class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt" data-itemid="@item.Id"></a> 
</div>
```

I have tried things like e.stopPropagation in the click event of the child, also something like this, but it still shows for an instant.

```
$("[data-toggle='popover']").click(function(e) {
        if (e.target !== this) {
            $(this).popover('destroy');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Could you please replicate this in `fiddle` or `snippet`?

Comment: I couldn't seem to get it to work in jsFiddle, but I have found a solution anyway, by using trigger manual instead of focus.